# difference between root executing command as sudo vs not using sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo, root, su

I have a Linux question regarding the sudo command and the root user.  If I log into the root user using the `su` command, what is the difference between the following two commands?

```
root> sudo ./some_executable
```

and

```
root> ./some_executable
```

is there a difference?  I am trying to use an executable and noticed that the executable works fine with the first command, but fails for the second command stating that I am not running the command as root.  I always thought that the sudo/su commands allow you to execute commands with root privileges and so doing the first command would be redundant.  However, I did noticed that the root user is in the sudoers file so I did not know if this is a bug in the executable or if there really is a difference between running a command logged in as root vs using sudo?

Comment: The fact that you get an error that you are not running as root is very weird. Can you try running `id` and `sudo id` and see if there is any difference?

Comment: Alternativly run `whoami` and `sudo whoami`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your environment variables will be different for the two instances.

sudo will be resetting some of your environment variables - read the man page for sudo and look at the `-E` option as well as the section on the sudoers config file.

Additionally your use of `su` and not `su -` to gain root means you do not have a true root environment when executing the file directly.

In summary, you have an environment mismatch between the two situations making one work when the other doesn't.